# How can I pro-grammatically update JAVA_HOME using chef - JRE

Tags: java, powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am able to install Java using chef resource 'windows_package' In my current chef recipe, I am hard-coding the value of

```
default[java][java_home] = C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_161
```

As value ***jre1.8.0_161*** changes from version to version. How can Chef programmatically get the version of jre installed?

```
windows_package 'JDK1.8' do
  source node['java']['java_rpm_url']
  action :install
  installer_type :custom
  options '/s'
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  only_if "!(dir 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment'  | select -expa pschildname -Last 1)"
end

env 'JAVA_HOME' do
  delim ';'
  value node['java']['java_home']
  action :create
end
```

Comment: Why tag this as `PowerShell` ?

Comment: @Theo-- If I get the same logic via PS, I can incorporate the same in Chef using powershell_script resource